# How can I get a Python decorator to run after the decorated function has completed?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I want to use a decorator to handle auditing of various functions (mainly Django view functions, but not exclusively). In order to do this I would like to be able to audit the function **post-execution** - i.e. the function runs as normal, and if it returns without an exception, then the decorator logs the fact.

Something like:

```
@audit_action(action='did something')
def do_something(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0] == 'foo':
        return 'bar'
    else:
        return 'baz'
```

Where `audit_action` would only run after the function has completed.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Decorators usually return a wrapper function; just put your logic in the wrapper function after invoking the wrapped function.

```
def audit_action(action):
    def decorator_func(func):
        def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
            # Invoke the wrapped function first
            retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
            # Now do something here with retval and/or action
            print('In wrapper_func, handling action {!r} after wrapped function returned {!r}'.format(action, retval))
            return retval
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator_func
```

So `audit_action(action='did something')` is a decorator factory that returns a scoped `decorator_func`, which is used to decorate your `do_something` (`do_something = decorator_func(do_something)`).

After decorating, your `do_something` reference has been replaced by `wrapper_func`. Calling `wrapper_func()` causes the original `do_something()` to be called, and then *your code in the wrapper func* can do things.

The above code, combined with your example function, gives the following output:

```
>>> do_something('foo')
In wrapper_func, handling action 'did something' after wrapped function returned 'bar'
'bar'
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but where is your decorator being called on "do_something"?  I'm expecting an @audit_action \n do_something('foo')

Comment: @ColinMac: I only touched the decorator; the `do_something` definition comes from the question, decorated with the fixed decorator. There is little point in repeating that sample application.

Answer (score 10):

Your decorator can handle it here itself, like

```
def audit_action(function_to_decorate):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # Calling your function
        output = function_to_decorate(*args, **kw)
        # Below this line you can do post processing
        print "In Post Processing...."
        return output
    return wrapper
```

Comment: The example the OP posted used a decorator factory called with an `action` argument. You need another layer of scoping or a class..